# Correct way to use parent environmental variables in maven in Intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have created a Maven Run Configuration in Intellij (Community Edition, Mac, Yosemite), and want to set up an Environmental Variable in the "Runner" tab of the configuration.  In the value of that variable, I was wanting to use a parent environmental variable (specifically, `$HOME`) for part of the value.

For example:
Run > Edit Configuration > Add New > Maven > Runner (tab) > Environmental Variables > Add New:

- name: `SOME_CONFIG_FILE`
- value: `$HOME/.config/file.json`

I have tried with `HOME`, `$HOME`, `$HOME$`, `${HOME}` and `%HOME%` and none of them were able to resolve properly.  Clicking on the "Show" for the Parent Environmental Variables show HOME with the proper value.

What is the correct way to set the value?

Comment: Your question actually helped me to find where to set the variables!

Answer (score 6):

It's not supported at the moment:

- [IDEA-85313](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85313) Provide ability to reference parent environment variables in Run Configuration dialog